# form validation using javascript in codeigniter

Tags: php, javascript, codeigniter, validation

hi i have a jquery table populate from datebase:

```
<?php 
$attributes = array('name' => 'users');

echo form_open('users/action',$attributes);?>
<table class="data display datatable" id="example">
    <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>Username</th>
          <th>Name</th>
          <th>Nickname</th>
          <th>Birthday</th>
          <th>Sex</th>
          <th>Address</th>
          <th><input type="checkbox" id="select all"></th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody> 
<?php foreach($query->result_array() as $row): ?>
        <tr class="even gradeC">
            <td><?php echo anchor('users/details/'.$row['usrID'],$row['usrName']);?></td>
            <td><?php echo $row['usrpFirstName'].' '.$row['usrpLastName'];?></td>
            <td><?php echo $row['usrpNick'];?></td>
            <td><?php echo $row['usrpBday'];?></td>
            <td><?php echo $row['usrpSex'];?></td>
            <td><?php echo $row['usrpAddress'];?></td>
            <td><input type="checkbox" name="checkID[]" id="checkID" value="<?php echo $row['usrID'];?>" />

              <label for="checkID"></label></td>
        </tr>
<? endforeach; ?>
    </tbody>
</table>
  <input type="submit" name="Delete" id="Delete" value="Delete" class="btn btn-orange" />
  <input type="submit" name="Edit" id="Edit" value="Edit" class="btn btn-orange" onclick="return validateForm()" />
  <input type="submit" name="AddUser" id="Add User" value="Add User" class="btn btn-orange" />
 </form>
```

as you can see below,, i use `checkID[]` so that i can get every id of each user.
i did make a `onlick` on edit button so that it will check if the id is empty or not. heres my js function

```
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
function validateForm()
{
var x=document.forms["users"]["checkID[]"].value
if (x==null || x=="")
  {
  alert("Please select user to edit.");
  return false;
  }
}
</script>
</head>
```

the problem now is that it will still alert even i check one user in the table..

even i use this:

```
<?php 
$attributes = array('name' => 'users' , 'onsubmit' =>"return validateForm()");

echo form_open('users/action',$attributes);?>
```

Answer (score 3):

`document.forms["users"]["checkID[]"]` will give you an array of *all* the checkboxes with that name. You're asking for the `value` of the array which doesn't make sense. You'll need to loop through them to find out if any are checked with something like this:

```
function validateForm() {
   var checkboxes = document.forms["users"]["checkID[]"];
   for (var i = 0; i < checkboxes.length; i++) {
      if (checkboxes[i].checked) {
         return true;
      }
   }

   alert("Please select a user to edit.");
   return false;
}
```

I haven't tested it but that code should give you the general idea.

Comment: it works if i have two users in a table, but if the table has only 1 user, it will still alert that i have not check any checkbox,,